# Finding motif in a sequence of characters

Tags: python, regex

I have also a dictionary in which the keys are ids and the values are long sequences made not only with K and M but also with some more characters which are not important for me.

```
li = {id1: "KKMKMKMKJASGKKKMOOGBMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM",
 id2:"MMKFJDFKFGKJKMKMKMKMKMJKJHFKMKMKM"}
```

I want to find the motifs of "`KMKMKM`" with the length of at least 6. it could be even or odd just equal or longer than 6. it should also be in a dictionary with the same keys but instead of the whole sequence, the value must be the list of motifs. like the following example.

```
results = {id1: ["KMKMKMK"], id2: ["KMKMKMKMKM", "KMKMKM"] }
```

I have wrote this code but did not return interested motifs.

```
{k: re.findall(r'(?:KM){6,1000}', v) for k, v in li.items()}
```

Comment: What do you mean by motif?

Comment: small sequence of K and M I am looking for.

Comment: Must they be alternating and start with `K`?

Comment: should not be two M(MM) or K(KK) together. one M and one K

Answer (score 3):

This one does the job:

```
((?:KM){3,}K?)
```

**Explanation:**

```
(             : group 1
  (?:KM){3,}  : non capture group, 3 or more times KM
  K?          : optional K
)             : end group 1
```

**In action:**

```
import re

li = {'id1': "KKMKMKMKJASGKKKMOOGBMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM",
 'id2':"MMKFJDFKFGKJKMKMKMKMKMJKJHFKMKMKM"}

res = {k: re.findall(r'((?:KM){3,}K?)', v) for k, v in li.items()}
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
{'id2': ['KMKMKMKMKM', 'KMKMKM'], 'id1': ['KMKMKMK']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
import re

stringA = "KKMKMKMKJASGKKKMOOGBMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM";
motifs = "KMKMKM";

m = re.search(motifs, stringA)
if m:
    print(motifs);
```

In reply to your comment below:

```
stringA = "KKMKMKMKJASGKKKMOOGBMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM";
motifs = "KMKMKM";
i = 0;

while True:
    seq = stringA[i:]
    i = i + 1;
    if (seq.startswith(motifs)):
        print(seq);
    if (len(stringA) == i):
        break;
```

Comment: thanks. but it returns only those with the length 6 but not longer. I need 6 and longer.